# how to add unique `div` to all course questions page?

Tags: content-management-system, moodle, canvas-lms

I am new in **moodle** and also not 100% idea about asking question regarding moodle issues

Is there any option in `moodle` to add a `div` at the top of all questions pages as a unique div ?

it should be editable as well

any answer and advice are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know moodle, Its not possible to add a new div on quiz pages easily, The easy way to add html/tags in moodle by theme which is applying in your moodle as current theme. If you add any tags on particular theme, it will be shown in this theme only.

Moodle theme has various layout, on which you can add/edit html/tags.

Please read paragraph under header '*The different layouts as of 21st April 2013' with this artcle*.[Various Layout](http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Themes_overview). which describes about moodle various layout. I am not sure but it may useful for you.

If theme way is not useful for you, then you will have to go with creating module/plugin for add html.

Comment: I have just creat `div` with in the **questiontypes.class.php**. Is there any option make the consents are editable from the settings ?

Comment: Technically I am not explore about this, Perhaps this link http://docs.moodle.org/dev/Admin_settings will do help fro you